# Not defining the type of variable (Automatic global variables)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I recently came across this http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp where I learned about "Automatic Global variables". Here is how you use it:

```
// code here can use carName

function myFunction() {
    carName = "Volvo";

        // code here can use carName
}
```

However, how high can it go? I am worried other files can access it to if its that global. If I am using AngularJS, can other controllers use it? Can other files use it?

Comment: What do you mean other files??? FYI: w3schools is not the best reference out there.

Comment: other modules. (which have their own controllers)

Comment: Global is global, anything can use them. There is no relationship between a JS file and scope, it is like they are all in one big file. That is why using `var` is important and not polluting the global namespace is important.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470488/what-is-the-function-of-the-var-keyword-and-when-to-use-it-or-omit-it

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, creating a variable without `var` is the same as setting it on the global object as a property (and in the browser, `global` is `window`:

```
nameWithoutVar = 1;
// the above is the same as
window.nameWithoutVar = 1;
```

This means that any other script loaded in the browser for the page can access `nameWithoutVar`, the same as they can access `location`, `document`, etc.

Global variables are considered an extremely bad idea for this reason, because *everything* is using the same namespace.  If you *must* use a global variable<sup>†</sup>, be sure to document it, and try to namespace it so that it is unlikely to conflict with any other variable.

<sup>†</sup><sub>If you're not sure, you probably don't have to.</sub>